# Vert.x Http Request not assigning parameters as configurations

Tags: java, http, web, httprequest, vert.x

I am having an issue using Vert.x HttpRequest class.
It is not keeping the values passed as parameters as request options/configurations.

Basically performing this:

```
    HttpClientRequest request = vertx.createHttpClient().request(HttpMethod.GET, 80, "localhost", "/");
    System.out.println(request.getHost());
```

Gives me this:

```
null
```

Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host you are accessing refers to the host header. not sure for what is it used, but the "localhost" is in the base object and do not have a default accessor.

```
HttpClientRequest request = httpClient.request(HttpMethod.GET, "localhost", "/");
request.setHost("myHost");
System.out.println(request.getHost());
// returns "myHost"
System.out.println(((HttpClientRequestBase)request).host());
//returns "localhost"
```